# Javascript Function parameter to target html ID and add CSS Class

Tags: javascript, onclick, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I am trying to display a gallery of coaches on a webpage by displaying images with a name. I would like to enable a popup window onClick that will display more information for each coach by toggling the CSS class .-enable {} by targeting specific container divs using their associated ID's. I setup the html so a popup window appears with a "close" button by toggling the css class .enable on that specific container.

I thought to use a really simple function with a parameter to select the id, then toggle a class on the id. In my example, everything wrapped within the first  tag is visible by default, and the following div is activated by toggling the css class .-enable. My example "Chris" is a coach and by clicking on the default container block, I activate function "coachWindow(coach)" and pass "Chris" as a parameter in the function to select the div with ID "chris" and toggle the CSS class.

```js
function coachWindow ( coach ) {
  document.querySelector("#" + coach).classList.toggle("-enable");
}
```

```css
.-enable {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="coachWindow(chris)"><div>
<div class="enlarge">
    <div class="chris-img coach-img-sizing">
    <div class="coach-overlay">
    <h3 class="coach-name">Chris</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

<div id="chris" class="coach"> <!--(-enable class appears here)-->
  <div class="lightwindow"></div>
   <div class="coach-box">
    <div class="coach-container">
     <h3 class="coach-heading">Chris</h3>
     <div class="image-container chris-img coach-img-sizing"></div>
     <div class="coach-text">
      <p>
      Text block on this coach.
      </p> 
     </div>
     <button onclick="coachWindow(chris)" class="coach-button">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wasn't sure about the querySelector options, but I saw an example with jQuery that looked like `$('#' + parameter)` capable of targeting `parameter` ID's

When I run `document.querySelector(chris).classList.toggle("-enable");` from the console, the popup box appears, however running the same id through function coachWindow returns undefined and typeError results.

How can I write my function so I can pass through any coach ID and display the popup window for that corresponding coach?

Comment: Where is your variable `chris` defined?

Comment: You need to quote `chris` to make it a string.

Comment: `coachWindow('chris')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much simpler than you think. First, don't focus on `id`s as this will make for a more complex and brittle solution. If you structure your HTML correctly, it's just a matter of showing or hiding the appropriate `div` by locating it with the DOM [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and [`.nextElementSibling()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) methods and then adding and removing a pre-set class with [`.classList.add` and `.classList.Remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). With this approach, it doesn't matter what the `id`s are (you don't even need to use them) and you can add/remove coaches at any time without having to modify the JavaScript. Just keep the correct HTML structure.

Also, don't use `<a>` elements just as a `click` event trigger. Only use them when you are navigating, otherwise it's semantically incorrect. Just about any visible element can have a `click` event set up on it as you'll see below. Along the same lines, you can style anything to look like anything, so even non-link elements can look like links or buttons or whatever.

Speaking of semantics, don't use headings (`h1...h6`) because of how they make the text look. In fact, never use any HTML element because of the built-in styling that comes with it. Use the right tag to describe your content and use CSS to style the elements later. An `h3` should only ever be used to describe content that is at a third sub-level in a hierarchy. That means that they should only ever appear as children of an `h2` and that `h2` needs to be in an `h1`.

```js
// Get all the "links" into an array
let links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("h1.coach-name"));

// Loop over the array of links
links.forEach(function(link){
  // Set up a click event handler for each link
  link.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Locate the outermost div of the clicked element and
    // remove the hidden class from the following element
    link.closest(".enlarge").nextElementSibling.classList.remove("hidden");
  });
});

// Get all the close buttons into an array
let closeButtons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".coach-button"));

// Loop through all the close buttons
closeButtons.forEach(function(btn){
  // Set up a click event handler for each
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Locate the nearest ancestor div that holds the popup
    // and add back the hidden class to hide the current popup
    btn.closest(".coach").classList.add("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.coach { 
  border:6px double #e0e0e0; 
  padding:5px; position:absolute; 
  top:25px; left:25px; 
  background-color:#55f; 
  color:#ff0;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:3px;
}

.enlarge h1, .coach h1 {
  font-size:1em; 
  margin-top:.5em;
  padding:3px;
  text-align:center;
}

.enlarge h1 { 
  border:1px solid #808080;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:2px;
  width:75px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.enlarge h1:hover { box-shadow:0 0 1px #606060; }

/* This will be set on the popups by default
   and then removed as needed. */
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="enlarge">
  <div class="chris-img coach-img-sizing">
    <div class="coach-overlay">
      <h1 class="coach-name">Chris</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="chris" class="coach hidden"> <!-- each popup is hidden by default via CSS -->
  <div class="lightwindow"></div>
  <div class="coach-box">
   <div class="coach-container">
    <h1 class="coach-heading">Chris</h1>
    <div class="image-container chris-img coach-img-sizing"></div>
    <div class="coach-text">
     <p>Text block on this coach.</p> 
    </div>
    <button class="coach-button">Close</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- ********************************************** -->

<div class="enlarge">
  <div class="chris-img coach-img-sizing">
    <div class="coach-overlay">
      <h1 class="coach-name">Mary</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="chris" class="coach hidden">
  <div class="lightwindow"></div>
  <div class="coach-box">
   <div class="coach-container">
    <h1 class="coach-heading">Mary</h1>
    <div class="image-container chris-img coach-img-sizing"></div>
    <div class="coach-text">
     <p>Text block on this coach.</p> 
    </div>
    <button class="coach-button">Close</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- ********************************************** -->

<div class="enlarge">
  <div class="chris-img coach-img-sizing">
    <div class="coach-overlay">
      <h1 class="coach-name">Steve</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="chris" class="coach hidden">
  <div class="lightwindow"></div>
  <div class="coach-box">
   <div class="coach-container">
    <h1 class="coach-heading">Steve</h1>
    <div class="image-container chris-img coach-img-sizing"></div>
    <div class="coach-text">
     <p>Text block on this coach.</p> 
    </div>
    <button class="coach-button">Close</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- ********************************************** -->

<div class="enlarge">
  <div class="chris-img coach-img-sizing">
    <div class="coach-overlay">
      <h1 class="coach-name">Alice</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="chris" class="coach hidden">
  <div class="lightwindow"></div>
  <div class="coach-box">
   <div class="coach-container">
    <h1 class="coach-heading">Alice</h1>
    <div class="image-container chris-img coach-img-sizing"></div>
    <div class="coach-text">
     <p>Text block on this coach.</p> 
    </div>
    <button class="coach-button">Close</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still very new to Javascript and have not used a couple of the methods in that code block. I understand it, but am still wrapping my head around writing it from scratch. It solves the problem, thank you!

Comment: If I could pick your brain with another question.. if at a later time, I wanted to add an arrow navigation to toggle from one popup box to the next, could I use the same code block and write: 1. An array targeting navigation arrows 2. nextElementSibling to hide/'enable' the next box in the 'links' array?

Comment: @JosephButterfield Yes. Using good HTML structures allows for great flexibility in what you can do down the road. If I've answered your question, please mark it as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer. And, up-vote all answers that were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is not complete, since i cannot see the css style that makes your div hidden. i assume it is something like this:

```
.coach {
  display:none;
  /* more styling... */
}
```

This happens because of CSS priorities. When the DOM experiences changes and the element is rendered again, it takes both CSS classes and process them. But, since both classes (what you define for coach and -enable) are together and both try to set display to different values, the rule that is at last is processed.

So, in order to fix this, you need to order your CSS rules in the following way:

```
.coach {
  display:none;
}

.-enable {
  display:block;
}
```

That way, if -enable is present, it will be the last style applied after applying .coach.

There are more rules about this, for instance, if you're applying CSS styles based on ID or element name, there are different priority rules. You can read more [here](https://marksheet.io/css-priority.html)

Comment: There's no need for the `display:block` rule at all. Just add the "hide" rule when you want something hidden and remove it when you don't.